# Can this SQL be done in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-4.0

i have a simple SQL query, but im struggling to replicate in LINQ

```
select top 1 * from tbl_CarTax tax
ORDER BY ABS(tax.C02_From - 286.0)
```

i have tried this below but i get the error... - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
TaxCost = (from tax in db.DB2011_Vehicle_CarTax
orderby Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(C02Level - tax.C02_From))
select tax).SingleOrDefault();
```

Any help is most appriciated

Truegilly

Comment: what are the types of the C02Level and tax.C02_From properties?

Comment: What are the data types for `C02Level` and `tax.C02_Form`? You might be having data type conversion issues.

Comment: C02Level is a double and tax.C02_From is an int :)

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for `Convert.ToInt`. Additionally, `FirstOrDefault` is the equivalent to `top 1`. `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception, if your query results in more than one row being returned.
Try using this code:

```
TaxCost = (from tax in db.DB2011_Vehicle_CarTax
           orderby Math.Abs(C02Level - tax.C02_From)
           select tax).FirstOrDefault();
```

In contrast to the other answer, I see no need to avoid using `Math.Abs`, because the Entity Framework knows this method and can convert it to SQL.

Comment: If he really needs to discard the decimals he can call `Math.Floor` that also translates well on LINQ to EF.

Comment: Just verified Linq to Entities converts Math.Abs to this transact sql function:  ABS()

Answer (score 0):

You can pull down all the data, then use Math.Abs on the record set (probably slow if there's a lot of info to pull down), or you can just do something like this:

```
(from tax in db.DB2011_Vehicle_CarTax
 let level = C02Level - tax.C02_From
 let abs = (level < 0) ? (level * -1) : level
 orderby abs
 select tax).SingleOrDefault();
```

There might be a more legitimate way to do this, but if this is fast enough it should work.

**Edit** - Actually, it appears that Math.Abs translates just fine to SQL. If you remove the Convert.Int32 it should work just fine.